# How to control a GPIO pin on the raspberry pi (general use) (python script)

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio, gpiozero

I want to control a gpio pin on the pi (4B 8Gb ram) with gpiozero.
I can't find how to simply control a pin... without the library thinking that it is a LED.
Coming from Arduino, there you can just use digitalWrite, does this library have anything similar to this?
In the documentation I was able to find this:
https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api_output.html#digitaloutputdevice
But can't get it to work...

Stil not sure which library is the best... (rpi.gpio doesn't support I2C or SPI so not using that)
But for now I just want to control a pin
but rather not like this:

```
from gpiozero import LED
pin = LED(5)
pin.on()
```

Thanks

Edit:

I did this for multiple pins.

```
import gpiozero
DigitalOutputDevice(5, True)
```

gpiozero is correctly installed (tested it with a led) and I had no errors wtih this lines...

Comment: Are you getting any errors? If not maybe you are giving wrong gpio number? I recommend [this](https://pinout.xyz/) website for checking it.

Comment: `DigitalOutputDevice` is the correct class to use. Perhaps you should show us what you did and why it didn't work.

Comment: idk if it would affect this code but in the background i am running another script... but i added an & at the end of the command so that it would be in the background (I don't know if i am saying it correctly, am new to the PI)

Answer (score 0):

You can start with a very simple snippet like this.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

led_pin = 12
led_interval = 5
GPIO.setwarnings(False) 
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(led_pin, GPIO.OUT, initial=GPIO.LOW) 

GPIO.output(led_pin, GPIO.HIGH)
time.sleep(led_interval)       
GPIO.output(led_pin, GPIO.LOW)
```

Comment: is this question solved? please mark it for future readers